# Bound of power series coefficients of a growth-order-one entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, power-series

An entire function $f(z)$ satisfies
$$|f(z)| \leq A_\varepsilon e^{2\pi(M+\varepsilon)|z|}$$
for every positive $\varepsilon$. I want to show that
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty}\ [f^{(n)}(0)]^{1/n} \leq 2\pi M.$$
Alternatively, we can state the result as
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty}\ (n! |a_n|)^{1/n} \leq 2\pi M,$$
where $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ is the power series expansion.

I can prove this result with Paley-Wiener theorem when $f$ is of moderate decrease; I've no idea otherwise. Note that this is a pretty good bound, since equality holds when $f(z)=e^{2\pi Mz}$, just to give one example.

---

P.S. Sorry for the bad question title, since I can't really come up with an illuminating summarization of this problem. Please feel free to edit if you think of something better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have

$$\begin{align}
\left\lvert f^{(n)}(0)\right\rvert &= \frac{n!}{2\pi} \left\lvert\int_{\lvert z\rvert = R} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}\,dz\right\rvert\\
&\leqslant \frac{n!}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\lvert f(Re^{i\varphi})\rvert}{R^n}\,d\varphi\\
&\leqslant \frac{n! A_\varepsilon e^{2\pi(M+\varepsilon)R}}{R^n}
\end{align}$$

for all $R > 0$. The right hand side is minimised for $R = \dfrac{n}{2\pi(M+\varepsilon)}$, which gives the estimate

$$\left\lvert f^{(n)}(0)\right\rvert \leqslant A_\varepsilon \frac{n!e^n\bigl(2\pi(M+\varepsilon)\bigr)^n}{n^n},$$

and taking $n$-th roots,

$$\left\lvert f^{(n)}(0)\right\rvert^{1/n} \leqslant \sqrt[n]{A_\varepsilon}\sqrt[n]{n!}\frac{e}{n}2\pi(M+\varepsilon),$$

from which we deduce

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left\lvert f^{(n)}(0)\right\rvert^{1/n} \leqslant 2\pi(M+\varepsilon).$$

Since that holds for all $\varepsilon > 0$, we have indeed

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left\lvert f^{(n)}(0)\right\rvert^{1/n} \leqslant 2\pi M.$$

Comment: Wow, this is surprising. In fact when I found I need to show this (this is actually an intermediate step of another problem), I tried Cauchy at first. I must have screwed up something because I concluded that Cauchy is not strong enough, and went on to look for other approaches for more than an hour. Phew, at least it is settled now. Thanks, you saved my day.

Comment: awesome! (I am adding (not completely) random characters, since just "awesome" is not an allowed comment)